# I got an installation error, and don't know what to do

Tags: android

When I run my application it does not launch, and shows me this message in Console:

```
[2012-05-20 17:36:58 - TravelersDictionary] Installation error:
INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE 
[2012-05-20 17:36:58 - TravelersDictionary] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2012-05-20 17:36:58 - TravelersDictionary] Launch canceled!
```

I did check my Logcat but there is nothing written in red.

Here is the last 5 logcat messages:

```
05-20 14:37:36.520: D/ExchangeService(438): Received deviceId from Email app: androidc259148960
05-20 14:37:36.520: D/ExchangeService(438): Reconciling accounts...
05-20 14:37:48.555: W/ThrottleService(75): unable to find stats for iface rmnet0
05-20 14:44:00.404: D/dalvikvm(75): GC_CONCURRENT freed 648K, 13% free 8475K/9735K, paused 12ms+11ms
05-20 14:44:32.975: D/dalvikvm(170): GC_CONCURRENT freed 397K, 13% free 6241K/7111K, paused 8ms+7ms
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the next error: `Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE` and as the error said you don't have enough space in your device to install the app, therefore delete some unwanted apps and other data and try again.

Comment: my application size is 3.6 MB, does this count too larg?

Comment: @user1283769 it's not too large at all, but maybe your device is full with data and then the installation is failed. Clear some space and try to re-install.

Answer (score 1):

it seems that your device is running out of internal storage space, where the application are typically installed. You have two options. Remove some application, or, since you are developing, if you are is going to target `API` level grater than `8 (Android 2.2)`, you can set the `android:installLocation="preferExternal"`, in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file. `Android` will try to install the application in the external storage, as the doc says:

> If you declare "preferExternal", you request that your application be
>   installed on the external storage, but the system does not guarantee
>   that your application will be installed on the external storage. If
>   the external storage is full, the system will install it on the
>   internal storage.